# Executing windows command lines without switching current directory

Tags: batch-file, command-line

Given a starting directory, I'm trying to play a certain number of command lines in sub directories, in a `.bat` file. A working answer would be this :

```
cd xx\yy\zz\aa
call bower install
cd ..\..\..\..\

cd mm\nn\oo\pp
call bower install
cd ..\..\..\..\
```

I just *feel* there must be a cleaner way, potentially one-liner, without the need to write the third line `cd ..\..\..\..\`.

**EDIT**

I should precise the starting directory is *unknown*, meaning the `.bat` file could be played from different machines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
set D=%CD%
if exist "%D%\xx\yy\zz\aa\*" (
cd "%D%\xx\yy\zz\aa"
call bower install
) else echo Directory not exist

if exist "%D%\mm\nn\oo\pp\*" (
cd "%D%\mm\nn\oo\pp"
call bower install
) else echo Directory not exist

::this make current directory not changed
cd "%D%"
```

Comment: I like this version. But what happens in case of error ? I want to make sure the current directory is not changed at the end of this `.bat`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to change the current directory to execute a file in a different folder. Just use the whole path to the file!

Say you are in `C:\Folder1\batfile.bat` (your current directory is `C:\Folder1`) and want to execute the file `myApp.exe` at `D:\Folder4711\Something\Somethingelse`. This will work: `D:\Folder4711\Something\Somethingelse\myApp.exe`.

Your current directory will remain `C:\Folder1`.

Comment: this could require `call` if there are resources in `myapp.exe` 's folder used by it.

Comment: bower needs to be called from the right CD, this won't work.

Comment: @npocmaka bower being a PATH variable here, could you give me the exact command to be played? I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use pushd/popd :

```
cd c:\mystartingdirectory
pushd subdir1\sub2 rem path will be c:\mystartingdirectory\subdir1\sub2
dostuff
popd rem path will be c:\mystartingdirectory
```

you can also use nested pushd/popd

Answer (score 0):

@MichaelS already has one valid approach which doesn't involve changing the working directory. However, if you do want to change the working directory but in a cleaner way than your suggestion, you can do:

```
pushd xx\yy\zz\aa
call bower install
popd

pushd mm\nn\oo\pp
call bower install
popd
```

From the help for pushd:

> Stores the current directory for use by the POPD command, then changes
>   to the specified directory.
>
> PUSHD [path | ..]
>
> path        Specifies the directory to make the current directory.
>
> If Command Extensions are enabled the PUSHD command accepts network
>   paths in addition to the normal drive letter and path. If a network
>   path is specified, PUSHD will create a temporary drive letter that
>   points to that specified network resource and then change the current
>   drive and directory, using the newly defined drive letter.  Temporary
>   drive letters are allocated from Z: on down, using the first unused
>   drive letter found.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to temporarily change the current directory is probably this:

```
pushd .
cd /D xx\yy\zz\aa
if not ErrorLevel 1 call bower install
popd
```

The `pushd` command puts the current directory onto a stack in memory and switches to the given one.
Now you can change the directory (using `cd`) as you like.
The `if not ErrorLevel 1` ensures that `bower` is called only in case `cd` succeeded.
As soon as `popd` is executed, it changes back to the directory stored by the most recent `pushd` and removes it from the stack.

Here `.` is given as the new directory for `pushd` which exists for sure. So if the target directory (`xx\yy\zz\aa`) does not exist, `cd` fails but `pushd` will succeed and the stack is always written. So the next `popd` will always restore the previous directory. If you called `pushd` with a non-existent directory it would not write to the stack. This is particularly important when you nest `pushd`/`popd`.

The `/D` switch at `cd` allows even to change the current drive.

---

#### Update

Another method is to check the exit code of `pushd` which can be accessed by `ErrorLevel`, hence `bower` as well as the command `popd` are executed only in case `pushd` succeeded:

```
pushd xx\yy\zz\aa
if not ErrorLevel 1 (
    call bower install
    popd
)
```

Answer (score 0):

For completion, turns out the best answer for my specific cas (using `bower`) was

```
bower install --config.cwd=xx\yy\zz\aa
```